# Printing a statement only once in a while loop

Tags: java, loops, printing, while-loop

This is probably very simple, however I have completely blanked and would appreciate some pointers. I'm creating a small game we have been assigned where we select numbers and are then provided a target number to try and reach using the numbers we selected. Inside my while loop once my condition hits 6 it asks the user to generate the target number, however once they do it prints the same string again "Generate the final string" how do I print this only once?

Here is the code if it will help.

```
while (lettersSelected == false) {

            if (finalNum.size() == 6) {
                System.out.println("3. Press 3 to generate target number!");

            } // Only want to print this part once so it does not appear again.


            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                if (finalNum.size() != 6) {
                    largeNum = large.get(r.nextInt(large.size()));
                    finalNum.add(largeNum);
                    largeCount++;
                    System.out.println("Numbers board: " + finalNum + "\n");
                }

                break;
```

Comment: Can't you simply put it before the while, outside the cycle?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but why don't you declare a boolean before the while with false value, check it in your if and set it to true when you entering the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done very easily.

```
boolean isItPrinted = false;

while (lettersSelected == false) {

            if ((finalNum.size() == 6) && (isItPrinted == false)) {
                System.out.println("3. Press 3 to generate target number!");
                isItPrinted = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if (finalNum.size() == 6)` is satisfied first and so the string is printed. However, during the next iteration of the `while` loop, the size of `finalNum` has not changed as the contrary of the condition is checked in the `case 1` of the switch and the size is not changed anywhere between these two statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag variable and set it to `true`, add a check for that variable in the `if` contidion and if the `if-clause` is entered, set the variable to `false`:

```
boolean flag = true;

while (lettersSelected == false) {

    if (finalNum.size() == 6 && flag) {
        System.out.println("3. Press 3 to generate target number!");
        flag = false;
    }

    // ...
}
```